# Biochemically speaking, why aren't the cell membranes of eukaryotic, multicellular organisms made of more heat-resistant stuff?

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, fats, lipids

**TL;DR: there are lipids out there that are more heat-resistant than those in current cell membranes, yet current cell membranes don't have them. Why?**

I've cobbled together [various](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/cell-membranes-14052567/#:%7E:text=With%20few%20exceptions%2C%20cellular%20membranes,and%20two%20fatty%20acid%20chains) [miscellaneous](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/glycerophospholipid) [sources](https://www.britannica.com/science/glycerophospholipid) stating [glycerophospholipids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerophospholipid) - [glycerol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol)-based [phospholipids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phospholipid) - are the majority of [lipids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid) in [cell membranes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_membrane).

According to [this source](https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD%3A_Biophysics_241_-_Membrane_Biology/03%3A_Membrane_Phases_and_Morphologies/3.01%3A_Membrane_Phase_Transitions), which itself cites lecture notes from one of [Roland Faller's](https://faculty.engineering.ucdavis.edu/faller/) lectures at UC Davis, and is fairly well backed up by [this table](https://avantilipids.com/tech-support/physical-properties/phase-transition-temps) and [this study](https://www.karger.com/Article/FullText/350122) (cmd-F the phrase "It has been shown that DLPC-DAPC") - the following [phosphatidylcholines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphatidylcholine) - phospholipids which are a subset of glycerophospholipids, have [choline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choline) as their head, and are common components of cell membranes - undergo a phase change (henceforth described as "melting") from gels to liquids at the following temperatures:

[image]

These results are consistent with [Wikipedia's table on lipid bilayer phase behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipid_bilayer_phase_behavior), and would imply that:

1. Dimyristoyl phosphatidylcholine/DMPC has a tail length of 14 [alkanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkane) - carbon atoms chained to other carbon atoms via [single bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_bond), with hydrogen atoms taking up their other electrons.
2. Dipalmitoyl phosphatidylcholine/DPPC has a tail length of 16 alkanes.
3. Distearoyl phosphatidylcholine/DSPC has a tail length of 18 alkanes.
4. Diarachidoyl phosphatidylcholine/DAPC has a tail length of 20 alkanes.

According to said Wikipedia page, the temperature at which lipid bilayers melt is determined by the strength of the [Van der Waals interactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) between their tails, which increase in strength as the tails increase in length (and significantly decrease in strength if there are any carbon=carbon [double bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bond) in their alkane chains). This, too, is consistent with the results in the table: the more alkanes, the more temperature resistance there is.

I've found many sources (more than I can cite) stating cell membranes melt/dissolve at temperatures between 40°C and 55°C. This would suggest that many cell membranes:

1. Are made of the middle two phospholipids: either dipalmitoyl phosphatidylcholine/DPPC or distearoyl phosphatidylcholine/DSPC.
2. Are made of phospholipids that are either 16 or 18 alkanes in length.
3. Melt/dissolve between 40°C and 55°C because that's when dipalmitoyl phosphatidylcholine/DPPC and distearoyl phosphatidylcholine/DSPC melt/dissolve.

However, diarachidoyl phosphatidylcholine/DAPC, also on that table, melts at 64.1°C and starts melting at 62.1°C, since it has more alkanes, a longer tail, and, therefore, stronger Van der Waals interactions. Moreover, [very-long-chain fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_chain_fatty_acid) can have up to *35* alkanes/carbons, which suggests they'd require exceptional temperatures to melt. [According to Parchem](https://www.parchem.com/getpdf-Geddic-acid-016950.aspx), for instance, [geddic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geddic_acid) - 34 alkanes in length - melts at 93-95°C, about twice as much as existing cell membrane lipids. Although geddic acid isn't a *phospho*lipid (it has no phosphorous, for instance), it seems that the melting temperatures of lipids are based off their tail lengths, not off whether or not they have a phosphorous-based head.

As such, some fatty acids out there are clearly much more heat-resistant than those in cell membranes, such as:

- Diarachidoyl phosphatidylcholine/DAPC, which has the same [hydrophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophile) head and [hydrophobic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobe) tail structure that more conventional phospholipids do - it's just longer. It melts at 64.1°C.
- Geddic acid. Although lacking the hydrophilic head structure of glycerophospholipids, it could probably be grafted to such a head; it appears to me, at least, that the hydrogen-oxygen bond on its tip could have its hydrogen removed and subsequently have its oxygen atom bonded to a phosphorus atom to attach it to a choline head, making an [ester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ester) out of it. It melts at 93-95°C.

These substances are much more heat-resistant than the lipids actually found in cell membranes. Why aren't cell membranes made out of these substances rather than the ones they're actually made out of? You'd think that heat-resistant cell membranes would be an evolutionary advantage that would be better at propagating themselves than less heat-resistant cell membranes.

Is it because, as the Wikipedia page on very-long-chain fatty acids points out:

> Unlike most fatty acids, VLCFAs are too long to be metabolized in the
> [mitochondria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion), in the [endoplasmic reticulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endoplasmic_reticulum) (ER) in plants and must be
> metabolized in [peroxisomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peroxisome).

That would suggest that they're simply too large to be produced, and that DPPC and DSPC are compromises: heat-resistant enough to be effective, but small enough to actually be built without using peroxisomes to do so. Is this the case?

This might be more of a question for Stack Exchange Biology, but I figured this might be a chemistry-related thing rather than a biology-related thing.

Comment: Warm-blooded animals have the luxury of being able to optimize function without having to "pay much attention" to temperature. If you want to learn about how to make high-temperature membranes, look at bacteria or archaea that survive very high temperature.

Comment: Here is a nice article showing amazing membrane lipid adaptations: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5487899/

Comment: @KarstenTheis Certainly - if I recall correctly, those organisms use ether bonds rather than ester ones, which radically increases the durability of their cells at the cost of something to do with flexibility and transmembrane proteins. I'm pretty sure, however (correct me if I'm wrong) that ether bonds don't work with multicellular organisms, which is why I'm referring to ester-bonded lipids here. I suppose I'll change the title, though.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE, [cross-posting](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/108906/why-arent-cell-membranes-made-of-more-heat-resistant-stuff) the exact same question is generally [not advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/1055085) on StackExchange.

Comment: @Domen Certainly, but I legitimately don't know whether this falls under chemistry or biology. It might be an evolutionary reason or based off of the size of mitochondria (biology) or it might be due to how longer alkane tails interact with cellular chemistry or how cell membranes of longer-tailed lipids are less permeable (chemistry). It probably falls under one more than the other, but the boundary between the two is so thin in this case that I can't see which side of it this question is supposed to be on.

Comment: Fluidity is important to the function of a membrane. Membrane that work at high temp don’t work well at lower temps

Comment: @Andrew Why? What does the length of a lipid's tail have to do with how functional a membrane made out of said lipids is?

Comment: If it was designed by humans, I would advice to ask the designer, why this way. As it was not...

Comment: For essentially the same reason that it affects the heat stability. A more rigid membrane is not a good thing. Read up on membrane fluidity and membrane function

Comment: This question is a cross-post from Biology Stack-Exchange.

Comment: It is a basic feature of the process of evolution that redundant features not relevant to survival tend to disappear over time (as effort spent on unnecessary functions is wasteful: this is why primates with ready access to fruit can no longer make their own vitamin C). Why would any living thing not residing on a hot deep sea vent or a volcano need to be very heat resistant? Only the small number of creatures in such environments use membranes that are more heat resistant.

Answer (score 3):

**The evolution of organisms tends to drive out features that are not necessary for survival**

The right question to ask here is: why *would* they be heat resistant?

The key features of most organisms have evolved to support their survival in the environment they live in. The majority or normal organisms live in relatively temperate regimens (often 10° to 30°) where heat resistance is irrelevant to their survival. If you were a fireman you might wish for heat-resistant skin but most people are not firemen and there are very few advantages to having that feature (and being people they can equip themselves with fireproof clothing).

This generalises across most living things: the features they have are matched to the environment they live in. Anything else is redundant and costs effort they do not need to expend. Let's imagine some species of insect that had two variants: one heat resistant and one not. The heat resistant variant would need to consume more food to create the different membranes than its less resistant variant. That is energy that can't be used to grow faster or breed faster. In a normal environment it would be rapidly outcompeted by its less hardy cousin.

But there *are* heat resistant creatures. Hot deep sea vents often support thriving communities of beasts that can resist hot and toxic environments (past the normal boiling point of water!) They do have all the adaptations needed to resist heat including heat resistant membranes. The reverse is true in extremely cold environments where many fish, for example, have blood and cells that are, in effect, full of anti-freeze to prevent ice crystals damaging their cell membranes.

But neither set of extremophile adaptations exist beyond those environments. They can't compete with the "normal" creatures that lack the (expensive) adaptations.

So heat and cold-resistant adaptation are *possible*. But, in most environments not *useful*. So most creatures or plants don't have them. The only places we see them are in environment where they *are* useful or even *essential* for survival. They would be a complete waste of effort anywhere else.

Most humans do not walk around wearing bullet proof clothing all the time, despite the survival advantage in a bullet-rich environment. That would only be useful in a war zone or, perhaps, an american high school.

Comment: The disadvantage of heat-resistant membranes is not just the "cost". They actually perform poorly at "normal" temperatures because they are too rigid. Some organisms that live in a wide range of temperatures (and don't have thermoregulation) adjust their membrane composition to maintain fluidity at whatever the current temp is.

Comment: @Andrew This is probably true. But it doesn't make much difference to the central argument. Rather it strengthens the central drive to eliminate costly features that don't confer any benefit by adding to the cost.